# How to continue with Unreal engine after crash?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal-5

I know that it is possible to do it so that when the engine (and maybe the game) crashes, it does not close, and continues to work. Who knows how to do it?

I know there are many ways to do something like this (try-catches, custom crash handlers..) but need to know how to do this for whole engine easily.

Comment: I don't know UnrealEngine, but I would be surprised if there was a silver bullet that would handle all the possible crashes...

Comment: Do you have a specific crash bug in your game that you're trying to recover from gracefully? Exhibiting the specific cause can help folks find appropriate solutions/work-arounds.

Comment: You can try wrapping the game in some sort of a launcher, which launches the actual game and handle game crashes such that if the game crashes, the app does not exit and instead fall back to the launcher, which then decide to restart the game or do something else.